# Запись числа с любым разделителем

Tags: php, javascript, html, yii2, form

Вообщем, есть форма обычная от yii2:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'price')->textInput(); ?>
```

Когда пишешь дробное число он принимает его только если разделитель точка, а надо чтобы оно подходило даже если вместо точки была запятая, можно было бы и маску приделать, но я не силён в регулярных выражениях.

Comment: http://demos.krajee.com/money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для числе удобно использовать инпут с типом number.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'price')->input('number'); ?>
```

Скорее всего используется неправильный валидатор. Возможно эта [страница с валидаторами](https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-tutorial-core-validators.html#double) поможет.